# Inverse trigonometric proving problem

Tags: trigonometry

How can I possibly simplify this —>

$\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\cos^{-1}(\frac{a}{b}))$+$\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\cos^{-1}(\frac{a}{b}))$

Here is what I did -- I tried to take $\cos^{-1}(\frac{a}{b})=A$.Found A as $\tan^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt{(b^2-a^2)}}{a})$.But couldn't open for the formula of $\tan(x+y)$.

Any suggestions on how to proceed would be wonderful. Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\tan\left(\frac \pi4+t\right)+\tan\left(\frac \pi4-t\right)=\frac{1+\tan t}{1-\tan t}+\frac{1-\tan t}{1+\tan t}=2\frac{1+\tan^2t}{1-\tan^2t}=2\frac{\cos^2t+\sin^2t}{\cos^2t-\sin^2t}=\frac2{\cos 2t}.$$

You should be able to conclude.

Comment: Great answer. You couldn't have made it clearer. Thanks. I'm going to upvote for you and approve your answer. Please think of up voting this post if you consider.